# SimpleCursorAdapter to CustomCusorAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to turn this code that I have for a `SimpleCusorAdapter` to a custom one, because I will want o be able to perform more actions provided that a `SimpleCusorAdapter` will offer, I was curious with this creation of a `SimpleCusorAdapter`, what a conversion would look like, I keep getting errors in my CustomAdapter but it really shouldn't be that difficult to convert I wouldn't think. Let me know thoughts. Thanks.

**CODE:**

```
private void fillData() {

    // Fields from the database (projection)
    // Must include the _id column for the adapter to work
    String[] from = new String[] { TestTodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY };
    // Fields on the UI to which we map
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.label };

    // this.getLoaderManager().getLoader(0);
    this.getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    // _adapter = new TestCursorAdapter(this.getActivity()
    // .getApplicationContext(), _cursor, true);

    _adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.test_pro_row, null, from, to, 0);

    setListAdapter(_adapter);
}
```

**EDIT:**

My Custom Cursor Class I'm trying to use

```
public class TestCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    static class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
    }

    public TestCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_pro_row, null, true);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row_sum);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        rowView.setTag(holder);

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        String s = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(TestTodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY));
        holder.textView.setText(s);

        if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category")) == "Urgent") {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_add);
        } else {
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.action_refresh);
        }
    }
}
```

The Errors I get -->

```
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at com.adapters.test.TestCursorAdapter.bindView(TestCursorAdapter.java:46)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:639)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-08 21:44:32.270: E/AndroidRuntime(4716):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Whats the question here? What errors are you getting?

Comment: actually why do you need to extend SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: Not extending simple cursor adapter but check my edit for what I am trying to use, as you can see was commented out.

Comment: so why are you extending CursorAdapter instead of using SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: I want to build off of it and do more than you can with just a SimpleCursorAdapter, the reasons are irrelevant, as I am trying to just get what I have there to work....

Comment: what can't you do with SCA?

Comment: I don't see why you persist asking that, it's irrelevant, I should be able to get the same thing to work with a custom adapter regardless, should I not?

Comment: sure, you can do everything, a) extending CA with 200 lines of cide and b) using SCA with additional 20 lines of code. What do you prefer?

Comment: Well if I am displaying things based on how my xml works and it's going to have button performing actions that do things with my content provider, I am going to need a custom CA or a SCA? in your opinion?

Comment: SCA the less code the less bugs

Comment: For what reasons would I ever need my own custom cursor adapter?